# FireMonkey Android problem with TIdHTTPServer

Tags: delphi, indy

I have an FireMonkey Android app with a `TTabControl`, `TWebBrowser`, and `TIdHTTPServer`.

I try to redirect HTTP clients to a new URL in the `TIdHTTPServer.OnCommandGet` event using the following code:

```
TabControl1.ActiveTab := TabItem2;
AResponseInfo.ResponseNo := 302;
AResponseInfo.Location := ARequestInfo.Params.Values['url'];
```

But I get an error:

> Checksynchronize called from thread $c6f02970 which is NOT the main thread.

How can I change the tab after the request comes to `TIdHTTPServer` component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `OnCommandGet` event is executed in the context of a worker thread. You are only allowed to access the user interface from the main UI thread. Move access to UI controls embedded into a call to [`TThread.Synchronize`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Classes.TThread.Synchronize) or [`TThread.Queue`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Classes.TThread.Queue).

```
TThread.Synchronize(nil,
  procedure
  begin
    Tabcontrol1.ActiveTab:=tabitem2;
  end);
AResponseInfo.ResponseNo := 302;
AResponseInfo.Location := ARequestInfo.Params.Values['url'];
```